# ASP.NET confirmation box showing twice

Tags: asp.net

I've searched for a way to display a confirmation box when a certain button is pressed.
The only problem I have, is that the confirmation box shows twice.
Code:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnDel" runat="server" onClick="btnDel_Click" Text="Delete">
```

and in Page_Load:

```
btnDel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure?');");
```

Comment: What about if you use the onmousedown attribute?

Comment: http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/103519.aspx see if this helps

Comment: THANKS Devjosh! Worked perfectly! Thanks. Can I make your comment as the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the button control you are using is devexpress button and it implements it's own ClientSideEventCollection in which you can add any javascript. you can do it like following

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnDel" runat="server" onClick="btnDel_Click" Text="Delete">
<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
    e.processOnServer = confirm('Are sure to save data?');
  }" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

Here `e.processOnServer` is a boolean which decides if the server trip should be executed, so we assigned the result of confirm to this boolean.

you can find more about ClientSideEvents on a dev express control, in the devexpress docs [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9448)

Answer (score 1):

Change your Page_Load code to:

```
if (! IsPostback)
    btnDel.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure?');");
```

You only have to add the onclick attribute once at the first load of the page.